# C++ foreach-loop picks mutable begin() even

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, foreach

When writing

```
for(const auto& val: my_container)
  sum += val
```

Visual Studio picks the mutable version of `begin()`, is this by design or a bug?

As I using a copy on write container, this is quite a performance issue in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. The "foreach" loop doesn't look at the qualifiers or the reference qualifiers of the iteration variable when determining whether to treat `my_container` as const. Workaround is to add the const explicitly

```
const auto& my_container_const = my_container;
for(const auto& val: my_container_const)
   sum += val
```

Comment: To make it a bit less verbose, `template<typename T> T const& as_const( T& src ) { return src; }` would give you `for( auto&& val: as_const(my_container) )`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour a `const_iterator` isn't a `const iterator` and in any case `begin` returns const depending on the `const`ness of the container not the variable that will store the return value.